# I am trying to code a Discord Music Bot with Python but i am gettin' errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to code a discord music bot but i am getting errors.
Discord.py library doesn't work for me.
The errors like "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'."

These type error for almost every attribute for voice_client. Can someone correct my code. Because i can't see my fault.

My Code is (in music.py);

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg


class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Ses kanalına gir")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 - 
   reconnect_delay_max 5',
                      'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("paused")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("resumed")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

My code is (in main.py);

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music


cogs = [music]


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())
for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)


client.run("My_Token")
```

Comment: I haven't played around with voice client before but I think it may be because you are trying to get the bot to join and play at the same time? For that, you could check if `ctx.voice_client is None` and if it is call the join method first.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.voice_client` doesn't have the `stop` property.

Solutions:
Either CTX or ctx.voice_client is None
Or, voice_client doesn't have the `stop()` function.